# Python Pandas Year To Date vs. Last Year To Date (YTD, LYTD)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to solve for how to get the values of year to date versus last year to date from a dataframe.
Dataframe:

```
ID      start_date   distance    
1       2019-7-25    2
2       2019-7-26    2
3       2020-3-4     1
4       2020-3-4     1
5       2020-3-5     3
6       2020-3-6     3
```

There is data back to 2017 and more data will keep getting added so I would like the YTD and LYTD to be dynamic based upon the current year.
I know how to get the cumulative sum for each year and month but I am really struggling with how to calculate the YTD and LYTD.

```
    year_month_distance_df = distance_kpi_df.groupby(["Start_Year","Start_Month"]).agg({"distance":"sum"}).reset_index()
```

The other code I tried:

```
cum_sum_distance_ytd = 
distance_kpi_df[["start_date_local","distance"]]
cum_sum_distance_ytd = cum_sum_distance_ytd.set_index("start_date_local")
cum_sum_distance_ytd = cum_sum_distance_ytd.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = "D")).sum()
```

When I try this logic and add Start_Day into the group by it obviously just sums all the data for that day.

Expected output:
Year to Date = 8
Last Year to Date = 4

Comment: can you post the expected output

Comment: @deadshot yes my bad forgot about that.
Expected output:
Year to Date = 8
Last Year to Date = 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the date into its components and get the ytd for all years with

```
expanding = df.groupby([
    df.start_date.month, df.start_date.day, df.start_date.year
    ]).distance.sum().unstack().cumsum()
```

Unstacking will fill with `np.nan` wherever any year does not have a value in the row's date... if that is a problem you can use the `fill_value` parameter

```
.unstack(fill_value=0).cumsum()
```

Comment: It seems to not be doing all the dates for each month. Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be adding all the dates such as for January I am missing the 4th and 5th date.

Comment: They surely don't have data in any year, thus are not par of the index

Comment: Yeah - I guess I was going to get to the YTD through a .iloc based upon today's date but if the row doesn't exist I will have to handle that.
This gets me close though so thank you!

Comment: You can include all dates before the groupby with `df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'start_date': pd.date_range(df.start_date.min(), df.start_date.max())}))`